# android ndk opengl creating protected context

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, egl

I am trying to create a protected context using opengl on android.

I am basing my code off of:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

Using the native activity as my base.

I have changed the EGL parameters to the following:

```
EGLint context_attribs[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3,
        0x32C0, EGL_TRUE,
        EGL_NONE,
};
EGLint surface_attribs[] = {
        0x32C0, EGL_TRUE,
        EGL_NONE,
};
```

And things seem to work on most devices, but a few devices are giving strange behavior (phone crashes, or not displaying at all, even though they claim to support protected contexts). A good example is the s9 qualcomm edition runs fine, until anything appears on the screen (overlay, navbar slide down, or sliding the samsung side-bar) which will result in a phone reboot.

Is there something I may have missed with setting up the protected contexts?

According to the khronos docs: 
https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/EXT/EGL_EXT_protected_content.txt

0x32c0 is the correct number for protected content.

--------------EDIT--------------

I swapped 0x32c0 over to EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT, and checked the extensions, and EGL_EXT_protected_content does exist. There are two devices I am working with that are having problems with this specifically (Samsung Galaxy s9+ qualcomm and Samsung Galaxy Tab S2). The S2 claims it supports the protected context, but then after using it, I get EGL_BAD_ALLOC. On the S9, everything runs fine, no errors, but the device will consistently crash on me after using it for a little.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using 0x32C0 instead of the token name: EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT?

Did you query that the extension string "EGL_EXT_protected_content" is in the supported extensions? that should be first thing you do.

Are you trying to do any of the actions that are not allowed? crashing could result.

Check your errors from eglCreateSurface and eglCreateContext. EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE would indicate not supported.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I will update my question with the info

Comment: The problem was addressed by samsung by upgrading the OS from android 8 to android 9. However this remains a problem on other devices. Looks like it is a problem with the samsung qualcomm implementation.

Answer (score 1):

About supporting this extension, It's started from Android 17 and also not **all** device provide this extenstion, so it's recommanded to check the device support.
Here is a code part to check the supported device by this extension :

```
fun isSecureExtensionSupported(): Boolean {
    val display: android.opengl.EGLDisplay? = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
    val extensions = eglQueryString(display, EGL10.EGL_EXTENSIONS)
    return extensions != null && extensions.contains(EGL_EXTENSION_PROTECTED_CONTENT_NAME)
}
```

and here is the part of code for init the protected context and surface :

```
 internal inner class ProtectedContextFactory : EGLContextFactory {
    override fun createContext(egl: EGL10, display: EGLDisplay, config: EGLConfig): EGLContext {
        val attrib_list = intArrayOf(EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, mEGLContextClientVersion,
            EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT,
            EGL14.EGL_TRUE, EGL10.EGL_NONE)
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtectedContextFactory Attrib_list : " + attrib_list.contentToString())
        val context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list)
        if (context === EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating EGL context.")
        }
        checkEglError("eglCreateContext")
        return context
    }

    override fun destroyContext(egl: EGL10, display: EGLDisplay, context: EGLContext) {
        if (!egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context)) {
            Log.e("DefaultContextFactory", "display:$display context: $context")
        }
    }
}

internal class ProtectedWindowSurfaceFactory : EGLWindowSurfaceFactory {
    override fun createWindowSurface(
        egl: EGL10,
        display: EGLDisplay,
        config: EGLConfig,
        nativeWindow: Any
    ): EGLSurface {
        var result: EGLSurface? = null
        try {
            val attrib_list =
                intArrayOf(EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT, EGL14.EGL_TRUE, EGL10.EGL_NONE)
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtectedWindowSurfaceFactory Attrib_list : " + attrib_list.contentToString())
            result = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, nativeWindow, attrib_list)
            checkEglError("eglCreateWindowSurface")
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "eglCreateWindowSurface", e)
        }
        return result!!
    }

    override fun destroySurface(egl: EGL10, display: EGLDisplay, surface: EGLSurface) {
        egl.eglDestroySurface(display, surface)
    }
}
    fun checkEglError(msg: String) {
        var failed = false
        var error: Int
        while (EGL14.eglGetError().also { error = it } != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS) {
            Log.e(TAG, msg + ": EGL error: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error))
            failed = true
        }
        if (failed) {
            throw RuntimeException("EGL error encountered (EGL error: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error) + ")")
        }
    }
```

You can inspired from those official code of google :

- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/common/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/util/EGLSurfaceTexture.java
- [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/d307a34/tests/vr/src/android/vr/cts/OpenGLESActivity.java](https://ProtectedEGLSurface)